# Using ngxtop for monitoring Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am using ngxtop to monitor Nginx.

```
ngxtop -l log_file_name
```

it takes 1 log file as input. Is there any way I can combine two log files into 1 , so that they both be monitored at the same time ?
OR
pass 2 files at the same time to ngxtop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing this in real time you can use the following:

```
cat access1.log access2.log access3.log > access_full.log
ngxtop -l access_full.log
```

Comment: Yeah, it is a way. But by this way, we cannot know that which request is coming from which log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
tail -q -f /var/log/nginx/*access.log | ngxtop -f combined
```